# Python unittest setting a global variable correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have a simple method that sets a global variable to either True or False depending on the method parameter.

This global variable is called `feedback` and has a default value of `False`.

When I call `setFeedback('y')` the global variable will be changed to be `feedback = True`.
When I call `setFeedback('n')` the global variable will be changed to be `feedback = False`.

Now I am trying to test this using unittest in Python:

```
class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_setFeedback(self):

        self.assertFalse(feedback)
        setFeedback('y')
        self.assertTrue(feedback)
```

When I run this test I get the following error: `AssertionError: False is not true`.

Since I know that the method works correctly, I assume that the global variables are reset somehow. However, since I am still very new to the Python environment, I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong.

I have already read an article here about mocking, but since my method changes a global variable, I don't know if mocking can solve this.

I would be grateful for suggestions.

Here is the code:

main.py:

```
#IMPORTS
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
from typing import List, Tuple

#GLOBAL VARIABLE
feedback = False

#SET FEEDBACK METHOD
def setFeedback(feedbackInput):
    """This methods sets the feedback variable according to the given parameter.
       Feedback can be either enabled or disabled.

    Arguments:
        feedbackInput {str} -- The feedback input from the user. Values = {'y', 'n'}
    """

    #* ACCESS TO GLOBAL VARIABLES
    global feedback

    #* SET FEEDBACK VALUE
    # Set global variable according to the input
    if(feedbackInput == 'y'):

        feedback = True
        print("\nFeedback:" + Fore.GREEN + " ENABLED\n" + Style.RESET_ALL)
        input("Press any key to continue...")

        # Clear the console
        clearConsole()

    else:
        print("\nFeedback:" + Fore.GREEN + " DISABLED\n" + Style.RESET_ALL)
        input("Press any key to continue...")

        # Clear the console
        clearConsole()
```

test_main.py:

```
import unittest
from main import *

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_setFeedback(self):

        self.assertFalse(feedback)
        setFeedback('y')
        self.assertTrue(feedback)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Can you show the `setFeedback` function, including the global variable, and the imports you use in your test?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I added the code. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, definitely helped - I added the explanation in the answer.

Comment: Arguably, the call to `input` and `clearConsole` don't belong in `setFeedback` at all; they are something that the *caller* of `setFeedback` might want to do after `setFeedback` returns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two problems with your test.

First, you use `input` in your `feedback` function, that will stall the test until you enter a key. You probably should mock `input`. Also you may consider that the call to `input` does not belong in `setFeedback` (see comment by @chepner).

Second, `from main import *` will not work here (apart from being [bad style](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-import-star-in-python-is-a-bad-idea/)), because this way you create a copy of your global variable in the test module - changes in the variable itself will not be propagated to the copy. You should instead import the module, so that you will access the variable in the module.

Third (this is taken from the answer by @chepner, I had missed that), you have to make sure that the variable is at a known state at test begin.

Here is what should work:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import main  # importing the module lets you access the original global variable


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        main.feedback = False  # make sure the state is defined at test start

    @mock.patch('main.input')  # patch input to run the test w/o user interaction
    def test_setFeedback(self, mock_input):
        self.assertFalse(main.feedback)
        main.setFeedback('y')
        self.assertTrue(main.feedback)
```

Comment: @chepner and MrBeanBremen First of all, thank you very much for the answers. I will read everything carefully tomorrow and adjust my code. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I have one more question regarding mocking:
What is the difference between `@mock.patch('main.input')` and using `with mock.patch(main.input)`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No real difference. The scope can be different, because in the decorator version, the patching always lasts to the end of the decorated function, and in the context manager version you can skip the `as` part, while in the decorator version you always have to add the argument for the mocked object. Apart from that, they are equivalent, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to mock anything; you just need to ensure that the global variable is in a known state before running each test. Also, using `from main import *` creates a *new* global named `feedback` in your test module, distinct from `main.feedback` which `setFeedback` is modifying.

```
import main

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        main.feedback = False

    def test_setFeedback(self):

        self.assertFalse(feedback)
        main.setFeedback('y')
        self.assertTrue(feedback)
```

Comment: Why doesn't he have to mock `input`? I don't see how that will work with `input` called in `setFeedback`, but I may be missing something...

Comment: Oops, I didn't read the question closely enough. I though he was asking about mocking the global before calling the function.

Comment: Ok - I now stole the `setUp` from your answer, as I had forgotten that in my answer...